# coordinate deprecated as of iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to grab the latitude and longitude of a users location.  I have a code which worked prior to deprecation, and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

The error is on the coordinate section of latestLocation.coordinate.latitude and latestLocation.coordinate.longitude, and the error states:  'coordinate' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift.

Thank you for your help.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

    latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)



    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
    }


}
```

Comment: `APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift.`  seems self-explaining, no? A Google search for `ios 8 swift get user location` seems to yield good results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following in your code

```
var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]
```

with the following.

```
var latestLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

This very well made article might help you:

http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/